# How Extract Part of the Text in Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Hopefully, this clarifies here I'm using nokogiri to extract javascript data. Everything works fine except one small details the need to resolve and I don't know how to remove the variable data.

I want to extract part of the text

```
<script>
    window.pageData={JsonDataType}
</script>
```

I only want the output `{JsonDataType}`.
my code which by the way gets everything

```
script = page.at("//head/script[3]").text
```

Comment: do you mean something like this? `page.at("//head/script[3]").text[/(?<=pageData=).*$/] #=> "{JsonDataType}"`?

Comment: @engineersmnky your solutions works thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would apply to `regex` to accomplish your task such as the following.

`match = script.match(/window\.pageData=(?<data>.*)/i)` and the data is captured in `match[:data]`.

I assume that `script` is string otherwise the regex rule may not work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the context.

If you clearly know the structure of page, you can do it just like that:

```
script = page.at("//head/script[3]").text.sub(/window\.pageData=/, "") #=> "{JsonDataType}"
```

Comment: Glad to help you. On SO it's a good practice to upvote or accept helpful answer instead of thanks.